# HP Envy 32 all-in-one bang & olufen audio driver

Tags: drivers, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa

Hi I have recently installed ubuntu, everything works fine apart from the audio.

In the audio output control panel I have 2 options: Speakers - Internal audio and Speaker - HP ENVY BT Speaker connected via bluetooth.

The audio doesn't work, I don't hear any sound. Can you help me? I don't want to go back to Windows 10 :-) Thanks

```
lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [103c:86c6]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me quite some time to figure it out, but you need to enable a GPIO pin on this setup. Execute the following lines, or put it in a script:

```
/usr/bin/hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x01 SET_GPIO_MASK 0x04

/usr/bin/hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x01 SET_GPIO_DIRECTION 0x04

/usr/bin/hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x01 SET_GPIO_DATA 0x04
```